# drag a view from bottom(hidden state)

Tags: android, touch, drag, gesture

[image: botto[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnX8T.png)

when drag to up i want to unfold the view like app drawer in launher ..
i am calculating the total height drag on touchlistener and adding it to myview..
but this does not seem to work.

```
@Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            float x1 = 0, y1 = 0, x2, y2, dx, dy, oldX = 0, oldY = 0, newX, newY;
            switch (event.getAction()) {

                /* User tapped down on screen. */
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.d("down", "action_down");
                    // User has tapped the screen
                    x1 = event.getX();
                    y1 = event.getY();
                    oldX = event.getX();
                    oldY = event.getY();
                    yStart = event.getRawY();
                    lastY = event.getRawY();

                    currentHeight = myview.getHeight();
                    Log.d("currentheight", currentHeight + "");
                    break;

                /* User is dragging finger. */
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    Log.d("move", "action_move");
                    // Calculate the total height change thus far.
                    float totalHeightDiff = event.getRawY() - yStart;

                    // Adjust the slide up height immediately with touch movements.
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myview.getLayoutParams();
                    params.height = (int) (currentHeight + totalHeightDiff);
                    myview.setLayoutParams(params);



                    lastY = event.getRawY();

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
```

}